# Implement a method from an interface without overriding

Tags: java, overriding, implementation

I have an interface `WithNaturalCoordinates` with method `setX` and a class that implements it (`RepetitiveRobotImpl`). That class (`RepetitiveRobotImpl`) also extends a class called `Robot`.
`Robot` also has a method `setX`.

Now my question is, how do I implement the method `setX` without overriding the `setX` from `Robot`?

My interface:

```
public interface WithNaturalCoordinates {
void setX(int x);
}
```

The class `Robot`:

```
public void setX(int x) {
    world.trace(this, RobotAction.SET_X);
    setXRobot(x);
  }
```

The class which implements the interface:

```
public class RepetitiveRobotImpl extends Robot implements WithNaturalCoordinates {

  public RepetitiveRobotImpl(int numberOfRepetitions){
    super(0, 0, Direction.UP, 100);
  }

public void setX(int x) {
    if(x < 0) {
      super.setX(-x);
    }
    else {
      super.setX(x);
    }
  }
```

Here the method `setX` is kinda doing both implementing and overriding.

Sorry, if it sounds kinda weird, I'm new to Java & programming in general.

Comment: What do you want to do? (You can just use `super.setX(Math.abs(x));`)

Comment: Maybe you want the parent class Robot to implement the interface?

Comment: Since it is same method signature your method overrides `setX` from *both* types and *that is OK*. What are you *actually* trying to achieve? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: For now your question looks like [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377). Try to [edit] it and clarify what you want to actually achieve.

Answer (score 3):

> Now my question is, how do I implement the method setX without overriding the setX from Robot?

You cannot.  If you have two supertypes with a method with the same signature -- the same name, the same argument types -- you can't override one and not the other.

Answer (score 1):

The method inherited from the parent class is enough to implement the interface:

```java
class RobotBase {
    int x;
    public void setX(int x) { this.x = x; }
}

interface IRobot {
    void setX(int x);
}

// no compilation error; the inherited method is sufficient to implement the interface
class Robot extends RobotBase implements IRobot {}
```